# how to connect firebase with libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, firebase-realtime-database, libcurl, wincrypt

I want to connect my code to firebase with using libcurl library and read datas i have function like this

```
static size_t my_write(void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* param) {
  std::string& text = *static_cast<std::string*>(param);
  size_t totalsize = size * nmemb;
  text.append(static_cast<char*>(buffer), totalsize);
  return totalsize;
}
```

and I have main function such as

```
int main() {



std::string result;
CURL* curl;
CURLcode res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL,"https://example-project-62811-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_OPTIONS, CURLSSLOPT_ALLOW_BEAST |
        CURLSSLOPT_NO_REVOKE);
    
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,my_write);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &result);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    if (CURLE_OK != res) {
        std::cerr << "CURL ERROR: " << res << "\n";
    }

}
curl_global_cleanup();

std::cout << result << "\n\n";
}
```

the code is working fine on other apis like https://api.chucknorris.io and the error that i get for trying to connect firebase is

- Trying 35.201.97.85:443...
- Connected to example-project-62811-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com (35.201.97.85) port 443 (#0)
- schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013)
- Closing connection 0
- schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with example-project-62811-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com port 443
  CURL ERROR: 35

edit-1
i also tried to write run from command prompt and it gives me same error and when i add add --ssl-no-revoke to script it worked

```
curl https://example-project-62811-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json --ssl-no-revoke
```

is working and then i tried to use this technique in my code

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_OPTIONS, CURLSSLOPT_ALLOW_BEAST |
        CURLSSLOPT_NO_REVOKE);
```

but it didn't work how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Does it work with command-line `curl`? Why setting `CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_OPTIONS`?

Comment: it work on command line with this command "curl https://example-project-62811-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json --ssl-no-revoke" withouth --ssl-no-revoke the command is not work it gives  this error :   curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schannel error code `0x80092013` means `Revocation Server Offline`.

In your case the Firebase CRL, `http://crl.pki.goog/GTS1O1.crl` as specified in the server certificate, could not be fetched.

That could be due to a misconfiguration of the Windows trust store, DNS, firewall, proxy, corporate network, or alike.

As a temporary (insecure) solution, you can bypass CRL verification using

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS, CURLSSLOPT_NO_REVOKE);
```

Notice the variable -  `CURLOPT_SSL_OPTIONS`. The one you try `CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_OPTIONS` is for proxy connections only.